# How to convert a column list of names to a list of columns names with double quotes after the column?

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a column in a dataframe with values that look like this:

```
0                             Albert Ross, Flyn Gibby
1                             Mark Cuban, Brian Hilbert
2                             Jim Lampert, Gilgan Smalls
```

To something like this:

```
0                             "Albert Ross", "Flyn Gibby"
1                             "Mark Cuban", "Brian Hilbert"
2                             "Jim Lampert", "Gilgan Smalls"
```

Does anyone know how you would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `str.replace`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['Albert Ross, Flyn Gibby'], columns=['names'])

df['names'].str.replace(r'(\w+\s\w+)', r'"\1"')

# Out[8]: 0    "Albert Ross", "Flyn Gibby"
```

Comment: Thanks! I did have one question though.  How would I get rid of the extra space between the quote and Flyn like here:  `"Albert Ross"," Flyn Gibby"`

Comment: sorry didn't notice that, fixed it. BTW I hope you don't have digits in names right?

Answer (score 1):

Split the values on `,` , then double quote each split values, finally join them back by `,`

```py
df['col'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x:', '.join(f'"{v}"' for v in x))

0       "Albert Ross", "Flyn Gibby"
1     "Mark Cuban", "Brian Hilbert"
2    "Jim Lampert", "Gilgan Smalls"
Name: col, dtype: object
```